# Javascript simplified if-statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm scratching my head trying to understand this very simplified if statement. When searching for the answer, all I find is answers related to ternary operators.

Anyway. Why is it that the first case below works, while the latter throws an `ReferenceError`? Just trying to understand how things work.

```js
true && alert("test")
```

```js
var x;
true && x = 10;
```

Comment: `=` you are doing an assignment not a comparison

Comment: I think it needs to be something like this `true && (x = 10);` to prevent the error otherwise it is interpreted as: `(true && x) = 10`

Comment: Maybe something, in which order it is interpreted. 
Might be like this (don't know, just thinking):
true && x = 10;
(true && x) = 10;
false = 10 -> Wrong

Comment: Don't write "clever" code like this. It provides no benefit, makes your code harder to read, and people will have to second-guess whether you wrote it by mistake.

Comment: @JLRishe: Sure, agreed. This is merely experimental, and the reason I'm asking is because I want to *understand* why these things occur. It's not uncommon that you have to look into other people's code, and I just want to grasp the logics behind it when bumping into these kinds of constructions. Which actually happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript seems to give higher precedence to `&&` than to the assignment operator.  The second line you gave is parsed as:

```
(true && x) = 10;
```

If you add parenthesis around the assignment, I think you will see the behavior that you were expecting:

```
true && (x = 10);  // Sets x to 10 and the whole expression evaluates to 10.
```

And just in case you needed a pointer as to why `&&` can be used as an if-statement, the phrase "short-circuit evaluation" might help.

Comment: It doesn't just "seem to" give higher precedence to `&&`, it does, in fact, give that operator higher precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @Rabbits: Thank you for the phrase. Now I know what to call it. :)

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). As the `&&` operation is computed before the `=`, your second example would end up making no sense : `(true && x) = 10;`

For your second case to work, add parenthesis this way :

```js
var x;
true && (x = 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

It'a [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

As you can see `&&` has higher priority than `=`

So `true && x = 10;` is actually `(true && x) = 10;` which is clearly wrong. You can only assign value to variables, and `(true && x)` is either `false` or the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

The result of alert() is undefined. So first example could be retyped as:

```js
var x; // x is now 'undefined'
true && x; // true and undefined is undefined
```

The second example is about operators priorities. Runtime evaluate expression as (true && x) = 10;

```js
var x;
true && (x = 10); // result will be 10
```